# Bind key-mousekey combination to a bash script

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Is it possible to map a key-mousekey combination to a bash script?

Such that e.g. when pressing [Ctrl] and (then) [left mouse click] a particular script is being executed?

Or a left+middle-mouseclick combination would also do.

(Using X, KDE on Ubuntu 14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE has a shortcut configuration interface but it appears to support only key presses and mouse gestures, not mouse clicks.

So instead you can use the independent program [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html). Add `xbindkeys` to the [Autostart list](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html) (System Settings → Startup and Shutdown → Autostart, use the “Add Program” button). Create a file `.xbindkeysrc` in your home directory containing something like

```
"/home/manfred/bin/myscript"
Control + b:1
```